# Google Maps Objects and Map Intergration

Tags: php, google-maps

Strange Issue.

I have the some code that queries a database and prases the results.

```
$MAP_OBJECT = new GoogleMapAPI(); $MAP_OBJECT->_minify_js = isset($_REQUEST["min"])?FALSE:TRUE;
//$MAP_OBJECT->setDSN("mysql://user:password@localhost/db_name");
// Make a MySQL Connection
$query = "SELECT * FROM `gpsdata`"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$print = '$MAP_OBJECT->addMarkerByCoords';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          $long = $row['longitude'];
          $lat = $row['latitude'];
          $router = $row['routername'];
          $desc = $row['desc'];
          $div = $row['div'];

        echo ("$print($long,$lat,\"$router-$desc\", \"$router-$desc<br><a href=\"./$div/$router\">Site Info</a>\");");
}
```

This is what a result looks like.

```
$MAP_OBJECT->addMarkerByCoords(-79.064250,67.175501,"xxx-SITE", "xxx-SITE<br><a href=\"./riv/xxx\">Site Info</a>");
```

If I manually create the entry the icon appears on the map.  If I run the following query the results just print on the screen, nothing on the map.  All of this takes place before the header info.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Not sure what to do, I have tried a few things, all with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be echoing out your statements before any templating has been done.

If you add:

```
ob_start();
```

above:

```
$MAP_OBJECT
```

This will turn output buffering on - and may sort the issue out